# D6: Adding HTML to CCK field data?

Tags: entities

In Drupal 6, I want to customise some CCK field data with some added HTML, but am not sure of the best/easiest way to do this. I couldn't find a CCK module to do this.

For example, I want to enter a URL (which is stored in the field), and then when it is displayed, it is embedded in some HTML. eg.

CCK Field data: filename.jpg

Output HTML: <div id="uniqueid"><img src="http://example.com/{{CCK Field data}}" title="Text"><br />Picture</div>

Answer (score 0):

Some answers [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2543466) including:

- [Theming individual CCK fields with templates and preprocess functions](http://friendlydrupal.com/screencasts/theming-individual-cck-fields-templates-and-preprocess-functions) (credit: Stefan Lehmann)
- [Theming Individual CCK Fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/62466)
- [Theming CCK fields within a content type](https://www.drupal.org/node/807330)
- [Custom Formatters module](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters)